# Chaplin.js routes

Tags: backbone.js, routes, coffeescript, chaplinjs

js / chaplin.js and I'm having some dificulties to find documentation about the chaplin routes.

I have the following code (cofeescript), it works in chrome but in firefox it tries to navigate doing a request to the server and it returns a 404 error. The server side is an ASP MVC 3 project.

Routes
    define ->
      'use strict'
       (match) ->
         match '', 'page#home'
         match 'Home', 'page#home'
         match 'Services', 'page#services'

PageController

```
define [
  'controllers/base/controller',
  'views/home_view',
  'views/services_view'
], (Controller, HomeView, ServicesView) ->
  'use strict'

  class PageController extends Controller

    historyURL: (params) ->
      ''
    home: (params) ->
      @view = new HomeView()
      return

    services: (params) ->
      @view = new ServicesView()
      return
```

Navbar (HTML)

```
  <a href="Home">Home</a>
  <a href="Services">Services</a>
```

PS: Another thing that I would like to know is, when the controller is called:

```
define [
  'controllers/base/controller',
  'views/home_view',
  'views/services_view'
], (Controller, HomeView, ServicesView) ->
  'use strict'
```

This is loading with AJAX both the Home and service view I would like to load only the one that has been actually called?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you instantiating  the router? By default it starts with pushState:true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answer on 
https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/issues/180